# How can I simplify this T-SQL to one query that groups the results by the number of items matching a value in a single column?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a requirement to generate a report that displays records grouped by the number of unique instances of an item based on the value of a single column.  For this we're displaying "line items" and want to group them in this way:

- Put all the records with unique line items (one record only) at the top of the report in one group.  The field we're keying off for the groups is LineItemNumber.
- Group other line items below that group, according to the number of times those line items are returned, starting with the least common to the most common.

There is other sorting criteria, but those two pieces are the core.  I've written working code that employs a table variable, and executes several statements to generate the output this report needs.  Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE @LineItems TABLE (
        PaymentID int,
        LineItemID int,
        LineItemNumber int, -- Group by this
        LineItemDescription nvarchar(100),
        PrimaryPayeeName nvarchar(101),
        SubPayeeName nvarchar(101),
        PaymentDetailAmount decimal(19,4),
        GroupCount int -- Exists only to eventually group by LineItemNumber.
)
INSERT INTO @LineItems (
        PaymentID,
        LineItemID,
        LineItemNumber,
        LineItemDescription,
        PrimaryPayeeName,
        SubPayeeName,
        PaymentDetailAmount
)
SELECT  p.PaymentID,
        li.LineItemID,
        li.LineItemNumber,
        li.LineItemDescription,
        payee.PrimaryPayeeName,
        payee.SubPayeeName,
        pd.PaymentDetailAmount
FROM    TCLReportPayment tcl
        INNER JOIN Payment p ON tcl.PaymentID = p.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN PaymentDetail pd ON p.PaymentID = pd.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN @Payee payee ON p.PaymentID = payee.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN LineItem li ON pd.LineItemID = li.LineItemID

-- Updating GroupCount just so the query can ultimately sort by groups of LineItemNumbers.
-- It would be nice to eliminate this.
UPDATE  @LineItems
SET     GroupCount = x.LineItemNumberCount
FROM    (SELECT LineItemNumber AS liNumber,
                COUNT(LineItemNumber) AS LineItemNumberCount
        FROM    @LineItems
        GROUP BY LineItemNumber) x
WHERE   LineItemNumber = x.liNumber

SELECT  *
FROM    @LineItems
ORDER BY GroupCount, LineItemNumber, LineItemDescription, PrimaryPayeeName, SubPayeeName, PaymentDetailAmount
```

This returns the output that I want. But I'd like to simplify this so that I can **eliminate use of that @LineItems table variable, and remove the secondary query that updates the GroupCount field**.  The above is verbose, and I imagine there must be a more succinct way to write the query and group these records as required.  How can I rewrite this to simplify the T-SQL?

We're using MS SQL Server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx) to the rescue:

```
;with LineItems as 
       (SELECT  p.PaymentID,
        li.LineItemID,
        li.LineItemNumber,
        li.LineItemDescription,
        payee.PrimaryPayeeName,
        payee.SubPayeeName,
        pd.PaymentDetailAmount
FROM    TCLReportPayment tcl
        INNER JOIN Payment p ON tcl.PaymentID = p.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN PaymentDetail pd ON p.PaymentID = pd.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN @Payee payee ON p.PaymentID = payee.PaymentID
        INNER JOIN LineItem li ON pd.LineItemID = li.LineItemID)
,lin as
      (select LineItemNumber, count(0) as LineItemNumberCount
       from LineItems
       group by LineItemNumber)
select li.PaymentID
      ,li.LineItemID
      ,li.LineItemNumber
      ,li.LineItemDescription
      ,li.PrimaryPayeeName
      ,li.SubPayeeName
      ,li.PaymentDetailAmount
      ,l.LineItemNumberCount as GroupCount
from LineItems li inner join 
     lin l on li.LineItemNumber = l.LineItemNumber
order by l.GroupCount, li.LineItemNumber, li.LineItemDescription, li.PrimaryPayeeName, li.SubPayeeName, li.PaymentDetailAmount
```

Additional info:
The benefit of using a common table expression over a table variable in this instance is that if the underlying table structures change, you wouldn't have to refactor your code to accommodate it. For example, if LineItemDescription changed to nvarchar(200) in the base table, you would need to change the data type in your table variable or risk truncation/ code breaking.

Comment: That's brilliant @rwking!  Works like a champ.  Thanks for your help. I need to brush up on CTEs. :)